# php CI $this->cart->insert($data) get null value

Tags: php, codeigniter, null, codeigniter-3, cart

I get stack in script. I used Code Igniter ver. 3.1.10. I use cart library in my controller

here my controller

```
    public function add_to_cart()
        {
            $idit=$this->input->post('id_item');
            $product=$this->Salesmodel->get_item($idit);
            $i=$product->row_array();
            $data = array(
                   'id'             => $i['id_item'],
                   'name'           => $i['name_item'],
                   'main_price'     => $i['main_price'],
                   'sell_price'     => $i['sell_price'],

                );

            $this->cart->insert($data);
            $rows = count($this->cart->contents());    // I want to find out rows count and result is null
            echo $i['id_item'];                     //get value, not null
            echo $rows;                                // get '0'

        }
```

model.php

```
function get_item($idit)
{
   $rslt=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_item where id_item='$idit'");
   return $rslt;
}
```

but in that script i always get null row count of the cart. 
I have to add this script in config.php :

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

I also created a new table with a name

> ci_session

but that returns the same result, my cart always has null row count and null data. Please help me with an error in the script that I made.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you print the result this line? `$i=$product->row_array();`

Comment: i use  `echo count($i); ` and get value **12**, count of my table cullomn.

Comment: Important, FYI: 
[**The Codeigniter Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.**](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save into the cart properly, these 4 array index are *required* :
`id` - Item identifier.
`qty` - Item quantity.
`price` - Item price.
`name` - Item name.

And the 5th index are `options`, which you could store all the additional attribute you need (should be an array though).

So you could modify the `$data` array like this :

```
        $data = array(
               'id'             => $i['id_item'],
               'qty'            => 1, // here I just manually set it to 1
               'name'           => $i['name_item'],
               'price'          => $i['main_price'], // here I changed 'main_price' index to 'price'
               'options'        => array('sell_price' => $i['sell_price']) // moved the 'sell_price' array here

            );
```

Comment: it's working. Now i know, id, qty, name, price and option can't be change. it's the problem, thanks.